# Get link tag returns error

Tags: jquery

Why does this return an error?

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="gfx/favicon.ico" />

var link = $('link[rel=shortcut icon]');
```

error:

```
uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [rel=shortcut icon]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the value of `rel` in quotes:

```
var link = $('link[rel="shortcut icon"]');
```

See the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) on attribute selectors:

> jQuery('[attribute="value"]')
>
> **attribute** An attribute name.
>
> **value** An attribute value. **Quotes are mandatory.**